# how to get world location and local location wrt ARcamera of tracked image and its prefab in ARTrackedManager?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ar-foundation

I'm facing an issue while working on my Unity project that utilizes ARFoundation. Specifically, I'm using the ARTrackedImageManager to instantiate a prefab on a tracked image and retrieve its local and world position. However, I'm encountering a persistent problem where the position values always return as (0,0,0).

I've double-checked my code and the ARFoundation setup, but I can't seem to pinpoint the source of the problem. Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve it? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!